# Constant Sum Voltage Divider With Thermistor/Temp Sensor

Tags: pwm, temperature, voltage-divider, 555, thermistor

I need a circuit with a thermistor/temp sensor that will essentially emulate a pot.  In other words, I need a voltage divider that varies with the resistance of the thermistor/sensor, but keeps the sum of R1 and R2 constant.  (Used to vary duty cycle with 555 timer PWM circuit.

I have a 10k thermistor, a tmp36 (though my supply voltage is 12, so that probably won't work) and an ad592, so if one of those worked it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care too much about the PWM frequency changing when the thermistor changes its resistance with temperature you can just use a fixed resistor for one side of the pot and the thermistor for the other side of the pot - I believe I know the circuit: -

[image]

To the left of the wiper, replace with a small value of resistance such as 100 ohms. To the right of the wiper connect your thermistor but, be aware - double check this - I may have the placement back to front. If the fan motor gets faster as the wiper moves to the right then it's OK!

By the way - lose the 470uF capacitor and definitely have a decent diode across the motor.